# How to join two tables with SQL to get names of athletes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables in my database currently, which for brevity sake, I have left out the columns not related to the question.

**events**

```
id   title                             org        date_time
---  --------------------------------  ---  -----------------------
221   UFC 226: McGregor vs. Holloway   UFC   2021-07-30 08:30:00-04
```

**matches**

```
id  event_id  fighter_a_id  fighter_b_id
--- --------  ------------  ------------
372   221          40            28
373   221          56            75
374   221         120           195
```

**fighters**

```
id   name         
--- ---------------  
28   Jordan Winskie
40   Mackenzie Dern
56   James Vick
75   Victor Cruz
120  Amy Snyder
195  Matt Brown
```

Is there anyway to write a query where I can get a list of rows back, with the fighters actual names added on? For example, maybe each row would look something like this:

```
id  event_id  fighter_a_id  fighter_b_id  fighter_a_name  fighter_b_name
--- --------  ------------  ------------  --------------  --------------
372   221          40            28       Mackenzie Dern  Jordan Winskie
```

Here's what my current SQL query looks like, I am stuck up to this point:

```sql
SELECT * FROM matches
WHERE event_id = <some event_id>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two `join`s:

```
select m.*, fa.name as a_name, fb.name as b_name
from matches m join
     fighters fa
     on m.fighter_a_id = fa.id join
     fighters fb
     on m.fighter_b_id = fb.id;
```

Comment: This works, SO won't let me accept an answer for another 9 mins...lol. Thank you very much. I will accept this when I get back.